# Can I set defaults for rsync in non daemon mode?

Tags: command-line, rsync, alias

Can I set defaults for rsync in non daemon mode? I know the daemon mode has this configuration file: `/etc/rsyncd.conf`

But I typically use the non daemon version in this sort of manner:

```
rsync -avzcO --exclude-from=/path/to/rsync/exclude/list {from...} {to...}
```

Is there a way that I can set those flags to be defaults?

I'm using `rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29` but I am happy to install a newer version if it has support for a default configuration file.

I suppose I could setup an `alias` but it just seems strange if there really is not a config file.

Comment: That's what putting a one line script in `~/bin/my_favorite_rsync`is quite good at. It may be less elegant than you'd like, but it certainly gets the job done with little fuss.

Comment: although it won't work with bash tab completion (i.e. for completing remote paths) I don't think...

Comment: @cwd It can easily be made to work, by declaring the completion for `my_favorite_rsync` to be like for `rsync`. In zsh it would be `compdef $_comps[rsync] my_favorite_rsync`, I don't know the bash incantation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can set those flags to be defaults?

No, at least not with a config file. Use an `alias` for this.

> I suppose I could setup an alias but it just seems strange if there really is not a config file.

I don't think it's strange. It's the same for tools like `ls` - if you want default options, you have to use an `alias`.